# Can Beats update existing documents in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Consider the following use case:

- I want the information from one particular log line to be indexed into Elasticsearch, as a document X.
- I want the information from some log line further down the log file to be indexed into the same document X (not overriding the original, just adding more data).

The first part, I can obviously achieve with `filebeat`.

For the second, does anyone have any idea about how to approach it? Could I still use `filebeat` + some pipeline on an ingest node for example?

Clearly, I can use the ES API to update the said document, but I was looking for some solution that doesn't require changes to my application - rather, it is all possible to achieve using the log files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not something that Beats were intended to accomplish. Enrichment like you describe is one of the things that Logstash can help with.

Logstash has an Elasticsearch [input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) that would allow you to retrieve data from ES and use it in the pipeline for enrichment. And the Elasticsearch [output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-doc_as_upsert) supports upsert operations (update if exists, insert new if not). Using both those features you can enrich and update documents as new data comes in.

You might want to consider ingesting the log lines as is to Elasticearch. Then using Logstash, build a separate index that is entity specific and driven based on data from the logs.